# Why pip --version and pip3 --version defaults to Python3.6 when Python3.7 is installed alongside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10, environment-variables

I just installed Python3.7.3.

```
pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 from c:\users\luca\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from c:\users\luca\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

I have both Python3.6 and Python3.7 set in my Windows 10 Environment Variables. Even switching the order of the strings in the PATH variable does not change the outcome.

Why `pip` and `pip3` default to Python3.6 instead of 3.7? How to change that?

Moreover, `py --version` defaults to Python3.7.3.

P.S. I know I can call `pip3.7 --version` or `py -3.7 -m pip --version`.

--------------- Edit --------------------

As requested, my users' %PATH%

```
C:\Users\luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
```

System's %PATH%

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\;C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
```

Comment: If `python --version` defaults to `3.7`, you could also call `python -m pip --version`

Comment: `c:\users\luca\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts\pip --version`? Can we see your `%PATH%`?

Comment: `python --version` is `Python 2.7.15`, which I don't even know where it is and why it's there :)

Comment: I can call `py -m pip --version` which gives me Python 3.7 but this does not answer the question.